# Bazel web-server 404 with ts_web_test

Tags: typescript, karma-runner, bazel

I'm developing a Typescript library and am attempting to configure Bazel's `ts_web_test`.  The tests are failing because `[web-server]: 404: /mylibrary/packages/mycomponent/spec/src/mycomponent.component.spec.js
HeadlessChrome 76.0.3809 (Mac OS X 10.14.6) ERROR: 'There is no timestamp for mylibrary/packages/mycomponent/spec/src/mycomponent.component.spec.js!'`

```
Karma version: 4.2.0
No browsers configured. Configuring Karma to use system Chrome.
27 08 2019 16:34:52.163:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v4.2.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
27 08 2019 16:34:52.167:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeHeadless with concurrency unlimited
27 08 2019 16:34:52.173:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
27 08 2019 16:34:52.894:INFO [HeadlessChrome 76.0.3809 (Mac OS X 10.14.6)]: Connected on socket G362JZZ9NCWpj9EFAAAA with id 40943039
27 08 2019 16:34:52.988:WARN [web-server]: 404: /mylibrary/packages/mycomponent/spec/src/mycomponent.component.spec.js
HeadlessChrome 76.0.3809 (Mac OS X 10.14.6) ERROR: 'There is no timestamp for mylibrary/packages/mycomponent/spec/src/mycomponent.component.spec.js!'

27 08 2019 16:35:23.014:WARN [HeadlessChrome 76.0.3809 (Mac OS X 10.14.6)]: Disconnected (0 times), because no message in 30000 ms.
HeadlessChrome 76.0.3809 (Mac OS X 10.14.6) ERROR
  Disconnected, because no message in 30000 ms.
```

```
# spec/BUILD.bazel

package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

load("@npm_bazel_typescript//:index.bzl", "ts_library")

ts_library(
    name = "mycomponent_jasmine_spec",
    testonly = True,
    srcs = glob(["index.ts", "src/**/*.ts"]),
    module_name = "@mylibrary/mycomponent/spec",
    deps = [
        "@npm//@types/jasmine",
        "//packages/mycomponent"
    ]
)


load("@npm_bazel_karma//:index.bzl", "ts_web_test")
ts_web_test(
    name = "test",
    deps = ["mycomponent_jasmine_spec"]
)
```

Comment: Adding `srcs = glob(["**/*.js"]),` to `ts_web_test` fixes for 404 error.  Now I'm only receiving `[HeadlessChrome 76.0.3809 (Mac OS X 10.14.6)]: Disconnected (0 times), because no message in 30000 ms. HeadlessChrome 76.0.3809 (Mac OS X 10.14.6) ERROR Disconnected, because no message in 30000 ms.`

Comment: were you able to figure out how to resolve the `Disconnect` issue?

Answer (score 0):

The 404's are due to not including the `spec.ts` files themselves in your ts_library. The `rules_nodejs` examples go over this in more detail now, but you should have your test library include the spec.ts files and have your other src files as dependencies like:

```
ts_library(
    name = "mycomponent",
    srcs = glob(["index.ts", "src/**/*.ts"]),
    deps = [
        "//packages/mycomponent"
    ]
)

ts_library(
    name = "mycomponent_jasmine_spec",
    testonly = True,
    srcs = glob(["src/**/*.spec.ts"]),
    module_name = "@mylibrary/mycomponent/spec",
    deps = [
        ":mycomponent",
        "@npm//@types/jasmine",
    ]
)
```

As for the disconnect issue, in my case it was due to some missing third-party umd bundles that I needed to add as part of the `bootstrap` argument. Unfortunately, the disconnect error is not specific and can be difficult to debug what dependencies are missing.